# How to return to the previous page after using `CTRL + L` command?

Tags: bash, terminal

For clearing the screen in Linux terminal, it is possible to use the shortcut `CRTL +L`. after that it seems that a new page is created. Is it possible to return to the previous pages? is there any command or shortcut without using the scroll bar?

Comment: The scroll bar belongs to the terminal emulator. The command or shortcut (if any) depends on the terminal emulator. Some emulators clear the scroll buffer (at least partially). Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1667569/432690); it's about `clear` but Ctrl+L may be similar. What is your terminal emulator?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for your reply. my terminal emulator is `GNOME Terminal`, v3.28.2 .